# nested listview.builder with List<TextEditingController>

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a nested listview.builder in my code.
Something like this:

```
listview.separated(
itemBuilder: (context, parentindex) {
    return Padding(
    ...code
    Listview.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, childindex){
            return Padding(
            ...code)})}
)
```

how do I use a textEditingController wherein each textfield will be unique.
I tried using `controller: _textcontroller[parentindex]` but each parentindex will be changed upon input of textfield.

I was thinking like `controller: _textcontroller[parentindex][childindex]` so that each textfield edit will be unique but i know above code doesn't work or do i need to change something to make it work?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly, create a **stateful widget** with each child to store your `TextEditingController` and make your code more clearly.

Flutter is widgets/components so don't put all things in to 1 widget.

**Example**: Copy this code below and paste to [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/) to see example app.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var todos = <Todo>[
    Todo('Go shoping, buy a snack'),
    Todo('Kick the ball'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Todos')),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: todos.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == todos.length) {
            newTodo() => setState(() => todos = [...todos, Todo('')]);
            return ElevatedButton(onPressed: newTodo, child: const Text('new'));
          }

          updateTodo(Todo? newTodo) {
            if (newTodo != null) setState(() => todos[index] = newTodo);
          }

          return RenderTodo(todo: todos[index], onChange: updateTodo);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RenderTodo extends StatefulWidget {
  const RenderTodo({
    required this.todo,
    required this.onChange,
    this.onDelete,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final Todo todo;
  final VoidCallback? onDelete;
  final void Function(Todo newTodo) onChange;

  @override
  State<RenderTodo> createState() => _RenderTodoState();
}

class _RenderTodoState extends State<RenderTodo> {
  late final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.todo.message);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    onChange(text) => widget.onChange(widget.todo.copyWith(message: text));
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          onChanged: onChange,
          controller: controller,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Input the message'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Todo {
  String message;
  Todo(this.message);

  Todo copyWith({String? message}) => Todo(message ?? this.message);
}
```

[image]